# Why can't I pattern match against a ratio in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

I'm trying to pattern match against a ratio:

```
isValid :: Ratio Int -> Bool
isValid (num % den) = ...
```

However, this yields:

```
Parse error in pattern: num % den
```

Interestingly, the `Data.Ratio` package defines the `numerator` and `denominator` functions in this way, but with the `:%` operator:

```
numerator   (x :% _)    =  x
denominator (_ :% y)    =  y
```

However, I don't have access to this latter operator.

Could anyone explain why my pattern match doesn't work and how I could fix it?

Comment: `isValid (num :% den) = ...`

Comment: @Dair, this gives me `Not in scope: data constructor ‘:%’`

Comment: How did you define `Ratio`?

Comment: @Dair I'm using the `Data.Ratio` package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible.  You could define a [view pattern](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns)

Comment: @luqui Why is a pattern match not possible? Just like you can pattern match against a list (x:xs) by using the `(:)` operator, it should be possible to use (%) for ratios, no? And why does the source use pattern matching but can I not access that operator (`:%`).

Comment: You'll have to import `GHC.Real` to access the `:%` constructor. `Data.Ratio` simply does not export `:%`. You cannot pattern match against `%` because it is a function, not a constructor.

Comment: Because the module does not expose the operator to its users. This is probably because it has invariants (eg a:%b should have b/=0 and gcd a b = 1) so it would not be safe to allow users to construct arbitrary values. And Haskell can not expose an operator just for pattern matching and not for construction (though there is no essential reason for this other than it would complicate the import mechanism)

Comment: @user2407038 That worked, thanks!

Comment: @luqui I think understand what you mean, that makes sense. I think in this case I prefer Python's "we're all adults here" philosophy then, where it's up to the user to use, in this case an operator, responsibly.

Comment: Haha. Yes Haskell's culture tends toward designing libraries that are very safe.  As someone who works with python professionally, I can say everyone likes to believe that they are the only one who is allowed not to follow the rules...

Comment: @luqui Together with pattern synonyms it is possible (though you'd have to give it a different name if you wanted to do it in the same module).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in this case you can just import the operator from `GHC.Ratio`, there is a general solution starting from GHC 7.8: [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms).

```
pattern num :% denom <- ((\x -> (numerator x, denominator x)) -> (num, denom))
```